# SQLAlchemy query using list of elements

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have set up a SQLAlchemy database that looks roughly like this:

```
class ChangelogEntry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    apps = db.relationship('App', secondary=app_changelogEntry)
    appGroups = db.relationship('AppGroup', secondary=appGroup_changelogEntry)

class App(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, index=True)
    appGroups = db.relationship('AppGroup', secondary=app_appGroup)

class AppGroup(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, index=True)
    apps = db.relationship('App', secondary=app_appGroup)
```

UPDATE:

```
app_changelogEntry = db.Table('App_ChangelogEntry',
    db.Column('app_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('app.id')),
    db.Column('changelog_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('changelog_entry.id'))
)

appGroup_changelogEntry = db.Table('AppGroup_ChangelogEntry',
    db.Column('appGroup_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('app_group.id')),
    db.Column('changelogEntry_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('changelog_entry.id'))
)

app_appGroup = db.Table('App_AppGroup',
    db.Column('app_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('app.id')),
    db.Column('appGroup_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('app_group.id'))
)
```

An App can be part of several AppGroups and users can create ChangelogEntries and can select what App/Apps and/or AppGroups this ChangelogEntry belongs to.

It looks like this:

[image]

Alright. I just want to get all ChangelogEntries that belong to e.g. App3 (App3 is part of AppGroups Group1 and Group2) and in this case Group1 and Group2.

I hope you can help me with that!

Comment: Please include the association tables as well.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly in that you wish to query both changelog entries that have a direct relationship to given app/apps, and those that have a relationship to a group that includes the given app/apps?

Comment: i included the association tables now. I hope it´s easier to understand now. But you´re right, that´s what i want to to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union might be a good match for the task at hand: find the union of changelog entries with direct app relationship and through groups. Using inner joins:

```
direct = db.session.query(ChangelogEntry).\
    join("apps").\
    filter(App.name == "App3")

groups = db.session.query(ChangelogEntry).\
    join("appGroups", "apps").\
    filter(App.name == "App3")

direct.union(groups).all()
```

Because of the many to many relationships the group joins might produce multiple rows for a changelog entry, but using a UNION instead of UNION ALL takes care of that. In order to avoid duplicate rows to begin with you could use semijoins/EXISTS:

```
direct = db.session.query(ChangelogEntry).\
    filter(ChangelogEntry.apps.any(App.name == "App3"))

groups = db.session.query(ChangelogEntry).\
    filter(ChangelogEntry.appGroups.any(
        AppGroup.apps.any(App.name == "App3")))

direct.union(groups).all()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to sql and sqlalchemy. Could you please tell me what join("apps")/join("appGroups", "apps") does. (i already now what joins are)

Comment: Have a look at [Query.join()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) documentation. In short in a single entity query you can pass the relationships used as the on clause of a join as a string. You can also produce a chain of joins, such as `join("appGroups", "apps")`, which is equivalent to `join(ChangelogEntry.appGroups).join(AppGroup.apps)`. SQLAlchemy handles forming the required association table joins behind the scenes for you, when you pass a many to many relationship as the on clause.